# How to register a user via json from ionic app to symfony2

Tags: ajax, json, symfony, ionic-framework, fosuserbundle

How can I register a user from an ionic app via json at my backend.

My backend is build with symfony2 and fos userbundle.

I implemented authentication/authorization via json web token which works seamless.

But I don't know how to register a user and write him through my user entity to the database.

Can anyone give my a approach on hopw to realize this or much better anyone has a little example for this issue.

thanks in advance

bambamboole

edit:

i've created a repository @ github:
https://github.com/bambamboole/symfony-jwt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a simple example to register a user from an AJAX call using [FOSRest](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle) and [FOSUser](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) bundles :

```
public function postUserAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $parameters = $request->request->all();

        $user = new User();
        $user->setUsername($parameters["username"]);
        $user->setEmail($parameters["mail"]);
        $user->setPlainPassword($parameters["password"]);
        $user->setEnabled(false);
        $user->setFirstname($parameters["firstname"]);
        $user->setLastname($parameters["lastname"]);

        $tokenGenerator = $this->get('fos_user.util.token_generator');
        $token = $tokenGenerator->generateToken();

        $user->setConfirmationToken($token);
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        $this->get('fos_user.mailer')->sendConfirmationEmailMessage($user);

        $view = View::create()
            ->setStatusCode(200)
            ->setData($user);

        return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($view);
    }
```

Hope it will help you.